# Date binder of multiple formats in java

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

How can I give multiple formats of date in `CustomEditor` in `InitBinder`?

Here is my binder inside controller.

```
@InitBinder
public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, 
            new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"), true));
}
```

Now I want date of format `mm/dd/yyyy` also, i.e. *both* formats are needed. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Spring documentation of DataBinder#registerCustomEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor)), *only one single registered custom editor per property path is supported*.

This means (as you probably already know), that you won't be able to bind two custom editors to the same class. In simple words, you can't have:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"), true));
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"), true));
```

---

However, you can register your own implementation of `DateFormat` that would behave as you wish, relying on your two required `SimpleDateFormat`s.

For example, consider this custom `DateFormat` (below), which can **parse** `Date`s that are either in the `"dd-MM-yyyy"` or `"mm/dd/yyyy"` format:

```
public class MyDateFormat extends DateFormat {

    private static final List<? extends DateFormat> DATE_FORMATS = Arrays.asList(
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"));

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(final Date date, final StringBuffer toAppendTo, final FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This custom date formatter can only be used to *parse* Dates.");
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(final String source, final ParsePosition pos) {
        Date res = null;
        for (final DateFormat dateFormat : DATE_FORMATS) {
            if ((res = dateFormat.parse(source, pos)) != null) {
                return res;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, you'd simply have to bind `Date.class` to a `CustomDateEditor` constructed over an instance of `MyDateFormat`, as follows:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new MyDateFormat(), true));
```

Comment: Dear Sir, according to this example: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-frameworks-webdatabinder/ , you can infact register multiple custom editors.

Comment: Sorry. After paying more attention, I realized that this question and your answer is about **one editor for one property**